# What are appropriate scenarios to use userdata, cloud init directives and metadata

Tags: amazon-ec2, metadata, aws-cloudformation, user-data, cloud-init

Please may I have some advice on when to use these settings appropriately? userdata, metadata and cloud-init directives all seem to accomplish the same goal.

Following the AWS documentation, when using userdata I can set up a lamp server in this manner.

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2
yum install -y httpd mariadb-server
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd
usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
```

Nice and dandy however I can also use cloud-init directives which for me already looks much cleaner.

```
#cloud-config
repo_update: true
repo_upgrade: all

packages:
 - httpd
 - mariadb-server

runcmd:
 - [ sh, -c, "amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2" ]
 - systemctl start httpd
 - sudo systemctl enable httpd
 - [ sh, -c, "usermod -a -G apache ec2-user" ]
 - [ sh, -c, "chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www" ]
 - chmod 2775 /var/www
 - [ find, /var/www, -type, d, -exec, chmod, 2775, {}, \; ]
 - [ find, /var/www, -type, f, -exec, chmod, 0664, {}, \; ]
 - [ sh, -c, 'echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php' ]
```

Then we have Metadata values in Cloudformation which, to be honest seem more long-winded than cloud-init directives. It goes something like

```
UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
            yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
            /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource AmazonLinuxInstance --region ${AWS::Region}
            systemctl start httpd
```

```
Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          packages:
            yum:
              httpd: []
              mariadb-server: []
              php: []
              php-mysql: []
      Tags:
        - Key: Project
          Value: Autoscale
```

What are appropriate scenarios to use each of these?

Answer (score 0):

In my view, the **main reason** you would consider using `cfn-init` and associated `metadata` is when you couple it with [cfn-hup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-hup.html).

One problem with `UserData` is that its updates a template do not lead to updates in your instances. This can be **problematic** if you for example, want to change some config setup of your `httpd` in your `UserData`.

The above issue can be **overcome** when you use `cfn-init` and `cfn-hup`. And for many, the ability to update the `metadata`, and subsequently, the processes on the instance is a **major advantage** over `UserData`.